# Handling "mobilephone" URL scheme does not work on real device

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I made a very simple app to open an `mobilephone` URL ("Tester"):

```
    let url = URL(string: "mobilephone:Test?index=1")

    UIApplication.shared.open(url!) { (result) in
        if result {
            print("success!")
        }
        else {
            print(result)
        }
    }
```

Then I added another app ("Handler") with a handler for that URL (this is in `AppDelegate`):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL,
                 options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:] ) -> Bool {


    // Determine who sent the URL.
    let sendingAppID = options[.sourceApplication]
    let source = "\(sendingAppID ?? "Unknown")"

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: source, message: url.absoluteString, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return true
}
```

And of course I registered this scheme in Project → Info → URL Types with the `mobilephone` as a scheme and my app identifier as Identifier.

This works great on the simulator. When I run both apps on iPhone 8 simulator I can open the tester, try to open the URL and it switches to the handler app and shows message box. So far so good.

But then I deployed both apps to the real iPhone 8 phone running iOS 12.3.1 and the URL is not handled. Tester app reports `false` from `UIApplication.shared.open` and the handler app does not start. I think I am missing some registration part but cannot figure it out. Any help please?

EDIT: it seems that when I change the scheme to some random name it works fine… Is the `mobilephone` scheme reserved somehow? I didn't see it on the reserved schemes list though.

Comment: That specific URL won't work. No idea why.. `mobilephone` won't work. Use a different URL?

Comment: This URL is opened by some device and I cannot change it…

Comment: Looks like that URL scheme is reserved by the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot possibly register such a URL. It is registered by the "Phone" application.

You can tell by going to Safari and typing: `mobilephone://test`.. It will prompt you to open the "Phone" application then say: "Safari cannot open that URL because it is invalid"..

EDIT: As of iOS 10+, that URL is no longer valid.. Here's a list of URLs blocked (along with the open settings update): http://appcofe.blogspot.com/2016/10/apple-blocked-41-app-url-scheme-on-ios_18.html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy2Ds.jpg

[image]
[image]
[image]

Tested on iPhone X (NQAJ2LL/A) - iOS 12.2 (16E227)

Comment: This is very strange but that's probably the best answer. However, why I cannot open this URL (`UIApplication.shared.open()` returns `false`) while it should be registered by Phone?

Answer (score 0):

Try `"mobilephone://Test?index=1"`

Comment: Still the same. And I think this is not the problem as I have another 3rd party app that opens this URL and I want to listen to it. And it also doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry i didnt realized this is a custom scheme. anyway maybe this will help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app

Comment: This is the exact tutorial I was following. Also, see my edit.